# c++ / object-oriented quick review?

Tags: c++, oop

I am looking for quick reference guide(s) for both OO and C++. I have a few technical interviews coming up and I just want a quick reference that gives the basic overview of the fundamentals. (Nothing too in depth, as I've learned it all once before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [C++ tutorial online](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

There is also [Bruce Eckel's Thinking In C++ freely available book](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/eckel/).

[C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) is searchable and [Herb Sutter's Guru Of The Week series](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/) feature many tricky puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Yegge at google has a couple of excellent summaries of interview questions [here](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/five-essential-phone-screen-questions) and [here](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/get-that-job-at-google.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a site that's dedicated to [Object Oriented Programming in C++](http://www.gillius.org/ooptut/index.htm).  It provides quick coverage of the basic concepts.

For pure OO info, you might want to review the basic terminology (not C++ related) on [Wikipedia's Object-oriented design page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design).

Answer (score 0):

[Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html) is a good jumping off point to refresh some things. For a terminology refresher it's hard to beat the [OO Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) page.